# Curselection не возвращает первый элемент listbox'a

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть список, в который занесены станции. Также имеется два листбокса для выбора начальной и конечной станции соответственно. При выборе 1го элемента из этих листбоксов нет никакой реакции, хотя прописан бинд на событие ListboxSelect. Curselection не работает только с первым элементом, с остальными всё в порядке.

```
      def onselect(evt):
        w = evt.widget
        k = w.curselection()
        if k:
            p = int(k[0])
            if p:
                lbl_condition["text"] = "Выберите\nконечную станцию"
                lbl_condition.pack()
                f = open('stations.txt', 'w')
                f.write(f'{w.get(p)}\n')
                f.close()
                stations.append(w.get(p))
                sstation_listbox.bindtags("all")
                estation_listbox.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    def onselect1(evt):
        w = evt.widget
        global buildpath
        global hidden_btn
        k = w.curselection()
        if k:
            p = int(w.curselection()[0])
            if p:
                f = open('stations.txt', 'a')
                f.write(f'{w.get(p)}\n')
                f.close()
                buildpath = tk.Button(master=frm_button, text='Построить маршрут', width=20, font=20, command=route)
                buildpath.pack(pady=(5, 290))
                hidden_btn = tk.Button(master=frm_button, text='Построить новый маршрут', width=25, command=reset_all)
                hidden_btn.pack_forget()
                estation_listbox.bindtags("all")

    j = 0
    i = 0
    frm_canvas = tk.Frame(master=master)
    frm_sstation = tk.Frame(master=frm_canvas, borderwidth=2, relief=tk.RIDGE, bg='red')
    frm_button = tk.Frame(master=frm_canvas, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
    frm_estation = tk.Frame(master=frm_canvas, borderwidth=2, relief=tk.RIDGE, bg='green')

    label_start = tk.Label(master=frm_sstation, text="Начальная станция")
    label_start.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
    scrollbar1 = tk.Scrollbar(master=frm_sstation)
    scrollbar1.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    sstation_listbox = tk.Listbox(master=frm_sstation, width=35, height=35, yscrollcommand=scrollbar1.set)

    label_end = tk.Label(master=frm_estation, text="Конечная станция")
    label_end.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
    scrollbar2 = tk.Scrollbar(master=frm_estation)
    scrollbar2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    estation_listbox = tk.Listbox(master=frm_estation, yscrollcommand=scrollbar2.set, height=35, width=35)
    for i in range(3):
        window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=75)
        window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=50)
    for k in dict.keys():
        if '(' in k:
            sstation_listbox.insert(tk.END, k[:k.find('(')])
            estation_listbox.insert(tk.END, k[:k.find('(')])
        else:
            sstation_listbox.insert(tk.END, k)
            estation_listbox.insert(tk.END, k)
        i += 1
    lbl_condition = tk.Label(master=frm_button, text='Выберите\nначальную станцию', font=2, width=20)
    lbl_condition.pack(pady=30)
    sstation_listbox.pack()
    sstation_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)
    estation_listbox.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    scrollbar1.config(command=sstation_listbox.yview)
    estation_listbox.pack()
    estation_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect1)
    scrollbar2.config(command=estation_listbox.yview)
    frm_sstation.grid(padx=5, pady=1, row=0, column=0, rowspan=4)
    frm_button.grid(pady=1, row=0, column=1, padx=93)
    frm_estation.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, sticky=tk.W, rowspan=4)
    frm_canvas.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема здесь:

```
        p = int(w.curselection()[0])
        if p:
```

Первый элемент списка имеет индекс `0`. И, соответственно, этот `if` не сработает для нуля, ибо `0` - это `False`. Во втором обработчике то же самое.

Comment: Спасибо, большое,  голову ломал из-за простой невнимательности)